# Find and Replace using MySQL Regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql table with column **CONTENT**.
**CONTENT** has some text with the following pattern:

```
<p class="notice">...</p>
```

I would like to change this pattern with

```
<div class="alert">...</div>
```

How can I use **MySQL regex** to achieve this replacement?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: use this `<.*?>(.*)<\/.*?>`

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it`s working for you.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE((REGEXP_REPLACE('<p class="notice">...</p>','[p]','div',1,0,'c')),'(notice)','alert',1,0,'c');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=151dda40e5a5cb440ff290039bdaa917

Comment: That requires MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB.